# how to get keycode value without passing event in JS for firefox?

Tags: javascript

I have a JSP page which has an event onkeydown and calla a Ajax function ajaxFn(this), this function calls a series of functions and then comes to common function ajaxInteraction(response,ajaxObj).
In this common function there is a subfunction which determines the keycode value,

```
ajaxObj.onkeydown = function(){

var keynum;
//  keynum = event.which;

if(window.event) // IE
{
    keynum = event.keyCode;
}
```

which recognises only the value from IE and does not recognises Mozilla.
I want to capture the keycode values in the same function for mozilla.
Am not able to capture the value using event.which since event is not passed here from JSP.

P.S: i cannot change the existing code.

Answer (score 2):

Events are the **only** method through which you will able read user's interaction.

There is no other way to do this, than to use events.

For Firefox use `event.charCode`

```
var code = event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
```